# How do I conditionally increase the value of the proceeding row number by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to increase the value of the proceeding row number by 1. When the row encounters another condition I then need to reset the counter. This is probably easiest explained with an example:

```
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
| Acct_ID |  Ins_Date  | Acct_RowID | indicator | Desired_Output |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|    5841 | 07/11/2019 |          1 |         1 |              1 |
|    5841 | 08/11/2019 |          2 |         0 |              2 |
|    5841 | 09/11/2019 |          3 |         0 |              3 |
|    5841 | 10/11/2019 |          4 |         0 |              4 |
|    5841 | 11/11/2019 |          5 |         1 |              1 |
|    5841 | 12/11/2019 |          6 |         0 |              2 |
|    5841 | 13/11/2019 |          7 |         1 |              1 |
|    5841 | 14/11/2019 |          8 |         0 |              2 |
|    5841 | 15/11/2019 |          9 |         0 |              3 |
|    5841 | 16/11/2019 |         10 |         0 |              4 |
|    5841 | 17/11/2019 |         11 |         0 |              5 |
|    5841 | 18/11/2019 |         12 |         0 |              6 |
|    5132 | 11/03/2019 |          1 |         1 |              1 |
|    5132 | 12/03/2019 |          2 |         0 |              2 |
|    5132 | 13/03/2019 |          3 |         0 |              3 |
|    5132 | 14/03/2019 |          4 |         1 |              1 |
|    5132 | 15/03/2019 |          5 |         0 |              2 |
|    5132 | 16/03/2019 |          6 |         0 |              3 |
|    5132 | 17/03/2019 |          7 |         0 |              4 |
|    5132 | 18/03/2019 |          8 |         0 |              5 |
|    5132 | 19/03/2019 |          9 |         1 |              1 |
|    5132 | 20/03/2019 |         10 |         0 |              2 |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
```

The column I want to create is 'Desired_Output'. It can be seen from this table that I need to use the column 'indicator'. I want the following row to be `n+1`; unless the next row is `1`. The counter needs to reset when the value `1` is encountered again.

I have tried to use a loop method of some sort but this did not produce the desired results.

Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to identify the group of consecutive rows starts from indicator `1` to the next `1`. This is achieve by using the `cross apply` finding the `Acct_RowID` with `indicator = 1` and use that as a `Grp_RowID` to use as `partition by` in the `row_number()` window function

```
select  *,
        Desired_Output = row_number() over (partition by t.Acct_ID, Grp_RowID 
                                                order by Acct_RowID)
from    your_table t
        cross apply
        (
            select  Grp_RowID     = max(Acct_RowID)
            from    your_table x
            where   x.Acct_ID     = t.Acct_ID
            and     x.Acct_RowID <= t.Acct_RowID
            and     x.indicator   = 1
        ) g
```